# Inner Join SQL table multiple times for the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have two tables (msg and users). I am trying to join these two tables together and print out the first and last name of the sender and the recipient as well as all of the message content if the message is marked as flag. I keep getting errors though, and have not found a good way to do this yet.

**Pictures of tables for reference:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYtzu.jpg

**SQL query I'm using right now:**

```
SELECT msg.*, users.uuid AS users.ruuid, users.uuid AS users.suuid, users.firstName, users.lastName
FROM msg
 INNER JOIN users ON users.ruuid = msg.recipient
 AND INNER JOIN users ON users.suuid = msg.sender 
WHERE msg.flag = 0
```

Comment: You need different table aliases.

Comment: remove "AND"...

Comment: Would you mind giving me a bit more info? I don't know if I understand what you mean. I'm new to SQL, so I'm still learning

Comment: @LasseEdsvik I tried that, I get error #1064

Comment: Please What you want expected result??

Comment: @A.Sang I said up in the description. "print out the first and last name of the sender and the recipient as well as all of the message content if the message is marked as flag."

Answer (score 0):

You can query the same table several times if you use different aliases. Also, note you shouldn't have an `and` between the two `join` clauses:

```sql
SELECT     msg.*, 
           r.uuid AS ruuid, r.firstName AS rfirstname, r.lastName AS rlastname,
           s.uuid AS suuid, s.firstName AS sfirstname, s.lastName AS slastname
FROM       msg
INNER JOIN users r ON r.uuid = msg.recipient
INNER JOIN users s ON s.uuid = msg.sender 
WHERE      msg.flag = 0
```

Comment: This doesn't fetch the first and last name of the sender though, only the recipient.

Comment: @Trae Good point. Edited my answer and added them to the select list

Comment: I tried this and got a massive error dump: https://imgur.com/a/E3pDM6H

Comment: @Trae had a redundant comma there, sorry about that. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
SELECT msg.*, u.uuid , u.firstName, u.lastName, s.uuid , s.firstName, s.lastName
FROM msg
INNER JOIN users u ON u.uuid = msg.recipient
INNER JOIN users s ON s.uuid = msg.sender
WHERE      msg.flag = 0
```